# Как понять, перетаскивает ли игрок мышку или просто нажал, Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть скроллер. Если игрок перетаскивает по нему мышкой, то скроллер должен ехать, а если игрок просто нажмет по объекту, расположенному на скроллере, то должна вызваться функция. Как понять, переаскивает игрок мышку или просто нажал, ведь обе функции OnMouseDown и OnMouseDrag вызывается в любом случае, если игрок нажал на экран, даже если не перетаскивал.

Comment: в момент mousedown запомнить координаты, в момент mouseup проверить что мышка не далеко от mousedown координат, с перетаскиванием - наоборот

Comment: Проблема в том, что если игрок перетаскивает, то нужно сразу выполнять действия, а не уже после того, как он отпустит. Но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите к объекту (scroller-у) компонент [`Event Trigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html).
Компонент имеет нужные вам обработчики - [`Drag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnDrag.html) и [`PointerClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnPointerClick.html). Компонент сам определит метод взаимодействия и подаст вам соответствующий сигнал.

Comment: я добавил Event Trigger, добавил свойство PointerDown, указал, что нужно делать, какую функцию выполнять, но эта функция выполняется и когда я листаю.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Попробуйте вместо `PointerDown` `PointerClick`

Comment: Я сразу его попробовал. Не работает

Comment: @МаксимФисман `PointerDown` - Когда ЛКМ опущена. `PointerClick` - Когда ЛКМ нажали и отпустили в том же месте. Это ведь то что вы хотите, не так ли? Если не работает советую задать новый вопрос. Отсюда без каких либо подсказок я ничего не смогу делать.

Comment: @МаксимФисман я смотрю у вас получилось.) В чём была проблема?

Comment: В Event Trigger'e много проверок, возможно я запутался и два раза проверил  PointerDown, не проверив Pointer Click. В любом случае, потому я еще раз проверил PointerClick и сработало))) Спасибо